# ListView onItemClick get row from Database?

Tags: android, listview

Im fairly new to Android development. I have a custom ListView that is populated with data from a DatabaseTable. The ListView-items consist of CATEGORY, DATE, TITLE and AMOUNT.

```
private class lvIncomeListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String item = ???;
        displayItemClicked("List-item Clicked:",item);

    }
}
```

Now, I want to add an OnItemClickListener to the ListView, so that when an item in the list is clicked, a DialogFragment will display the data from that particular row in the Database that is shown in the ListView, like

"Item Clicked: Category: food, Date: 17/10/25, Title: Restaurant, Amount: 20sek"

... how is the best way to go about to achieve this?

Comment: I have a custom adapter I have created.

Comment: I got good help down below, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a custom adapter, I assume you have a custom class where you store your list data maybe like this:

```
public class YourListData {

    private String catagory;
    private String date;

    public YourListData(){
    }


    public void setCatagory(String cat){ this.catagory = cat; }
    public void setDate(String date){ this.date = date; }

    public String getCatagory(){ return this.catagory; }
    public String getDate() { return this.date; }
}
```

Now in your `onItemClick` method in your `Activity` get the list data like this:

```
mYourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        YourListData data = (YourListData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String cat = data.getCatagory();
        String date = data.getDate();
        //...

        //Send data to your fragment
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, I was really stuck at this part, now with your help it all becomes quite simple :) Thank you very much!